# click on button in greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, firefox, button, click, greasemonkey

```
<a class="js-open-panel action-button" target="video-download" href="#">
        <em><span class="icon-16x16 icon-download"></span> Download</em></a>
```

xpath using firebug
/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/section[3]/a[4]

i want to click this button but no thing worked all the """ getElementBy """

i read a book  big size by searching but nothing worked

```
/*
function clickc(x)
{
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('em')[7];
var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
evt.initEvent("click", true, true);
el.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
setTimeout (clickc , 1);
*/
/*
document.getElementsByClassName("js-open-panel action-button").click();
*/

/*
function clickc(x)
{
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('em')[7].click();
click(x);
}
setTimeout (clickc , 1);
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the button is not loaded by AJAX, the following should work:

```
var dwnldBttn   = document.querySelector (
    "a.js-open-panel.action-button[target='video-download']"
);
var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
dwnldBttn.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
```

Note that `querySelector()` works off of CSS selectors (which Firebug will also show) versus the XPath.

---

---

From the comments, it sounds like AJAX is not loading the button (but it may be used to activate it).

Use this complete script to start.  Change nothing except the `@include` directive.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

setTimeout (clickDownloadButton, 1111);

function clickDownloadButton () {
    var dwnldBttn   = document.querySelector (
        "a.js-open-panel.action-button[target='video-download']"
    );
    var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
    dwnldBttn.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
```

Comment: it did not work --- as for it is ajax or not i do not have a background to depend on it to answer that--- i.e very new and only know what i use in greasemonkey and so far so little ------ the CSS path  ::      html.not-ie body#top.page-videos div.master-site-wrapper div#main section.video-action-bar a.js-open-panel

Comment: Two things... First: Open Firefox's console (Press *Control-Shift-K*) and paste in the code from my answer and press enter.  Does it work?

Comment: Second: Disable javascript (Menu: *Tools -> Options -> Content*, then uncheck *Enable JavaScript*.  Then reload the page.  Does the button still appear?  If it does not, then it is loaded by AJAX.

Comment: it worked now --- but i test my upper solution on it most of them worked -i deemed it useless i found it while i was searching so i am new to it also - but i need them work through greasemonkey and that is not happening do you have a clue ------ i am really grateful for you help thanks a lot

Comment: Did you load the page with JS turned off?

Comment: i works only through the console - and i disabled the  js the button appear but it does not function

Comment: Either the button is getting *activated* (not loaded, based on your comments) by JS, or the Greasemonkey script is crashing on something else.  Disable or delete/uninstall the old script and try the one from my updated answer.  Change nothing but the `@include` line.

Comment: that is really aw wonderfull gooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooal  really thanks for your help it works now